# Magento Controller override Multiple times

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides, controllers

I am trying to override Mage_Checkout's CartController's action addAction() but its not happening to override. Following is the scenario,

> Community Module overriding just "protected function _goBack()" of Mage of CartController.php

```
<checkout>
   <args>
      <modules>
           <Idev_OneStepCheckout before="Mage_Checkout">
              Idev_OneStepCheckout
           </Idev_OneStepCheckout>
     </modules>
  </args>
</checkout>
```

> Local Module overriding just "AjaxController.php"of community Module

```
<onestepcheckout>
    <args>
      <modules>
         <WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl before="Idev_OneStepCheckout">
             WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl
        </WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl>
     </modules>
   </args>
</onestepcheckout>
```

untill here everything working fine. But now I am need to override CartController.php 's addAction() in separate local module.

> Second Local Module to override "CartController.php" 's addAction()

```
<onestepcheckout>
  <args>
    <modules>
        <JakeSharp_Waterlee before="Idev_OneStepCheckout">
            JakeSharp_Waterlee
        </JakeSharp_Waterlee>
    </modules>
  </args>
</onestepcheckout>
```

CartController.php

```
require_once  Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Idev_OneStepCheckout').DS.'CartController.php';
class JakeSharp_Waterlee_CartController extends Idev_OneStepCheckout_CartController {
  public function addAction(){
     die('Dead');
  }
}
```

But its not doing in this controller.. Can anyone please guide me if I am making any mistake... Thanks

Comment: try changing to `<JakeSharp_Waterlee before="WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl">` and require_once `CartController.php` of `WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl` module

Comment: But WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl module does not has CartController.php , so you think it make sense to call a file which is not overridden in that module...?

Comment: Then just override whatever controller that's extending the "AjaxController.php"of community Module

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the WoofDigital module with your new local module.  You should also set up the module dependency correctly in your `app/etc/modules/moduleName.xml` file as well.  This way you config is loaded in the correct order.

Comment: But WoofDigital module is not abstracting CartController.php of community / Mage module... but i need to override CartController.php in my new local module.....

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl` instead of `Idev_OneStepCheckout` module in your local module. ie

```
<onestepcheckout>
  <args>
    <modules>
        <JakeSharp_Waterlee before="WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl">
            JakeSharp_Waterlee
        </JakeSharp_Waterlee>
    </modules>
  </args>
</onestepcheckout>
```

Your controller, you can keep as it is, since `WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl` do not rewrite `CartController.php`.

But you need to add dependencies in your local module in order to properly load them in order. So do this:

File : `app/etc/modules/JakeSharp_Waterlee.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <JakeSharp_Waterlee>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl />
                <Idev_OneStepCheckout />
            </depends>
        </JakeSharp_Waterlee>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: WoofDigital_OneStepCheckoutPhl module is not abstracting CartController.php, and I need to overriden the method from CartController.php
CartController.php is getting overridden in community module, though the method i want to override is not even getting overriden in community module too.